# How to add UIImageView in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uialertcontroller

I want `UIAlertController` to present an alert with `UIImageView` in an `ActionSheet`. But when I run the application it is terminating.

This is my code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                  message:@"Welcome"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *okButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:OK
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                            handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                            {
                            }];
[alert addAction:okButton];
UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,50,50)];
imgv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kaga.jpg"];
[alert setValue:imgv forKey:@"image"];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059305/add-image-to-uialertcontroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to add an image to a `UIAlertController` according to Apple Doc.

if you want then you can create your own custom view like:

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

If you want to take image appear on `button`
then Try like this:

```
UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                              message:@"Welcome"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                            handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                              //Do some thing here
                            }];

[okButton setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"kaga.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];

[alert addAction:okButton];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks but picture not appear

Comment: Whats the issue you facing now?

Comment: I want use uialertcontroller show picture in alerts message box. but I use `[alert setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"kaga.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];` it show `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.`

Comment: no It appear in ok button I want to show in message like http://i.stack.imgur.com/kuY0O.png

Comment: ohh..now i got exactly what you want... wait for few minutes.. I will tell your solution..:)

Comment: See my answer bro.. i hope it will provide some important information...@YasuhiroKondo

Comment: Yes, all the best..:).. if its helpful then you can accept my answer:)

Comment: Is this acceptable since Apple docs don't allow subclassing. I'm assuming they don't allow extension either. But they do have this kind of alert when you Airdrop something.

Answer (score 9):

You could add an image above the title label by subclassing `UIAlertController` and adding `\n` to the title string to make space for the `UIImageView`. You'd have to compute the layout based on the font size. For images in the `UIAlertAction` use `KVC` like so: `self.setValue(image, forKey: "image")`. I would recommend to use an extension that checks for `responds(to:)`.

[Here is sample implementation.](http://www.stringcode.co.uk/alertviewcontroller/)

[image]

```
extension UIAlertAction {

    /// Image to display left of the action title
    var actionImage: UIImage? {
        get {
            if self.responds(to: Selector(Constants.imageKey)) {
                return self.value(forKey: Constants.imageKey) as? UIImage
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if self.responds(to: Selector(Constants.imageKey)) {
                self.setValue(newValue, forKey: Constants.imageKey)
            }
        }
    }

    private struct Constants {
        static var imageKey = "image"
    }
}
```

Comment: @jtth I'm not a C# developer, so I don't know. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
UIImageView *imgv=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,50,50)];
    imgv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"kaga.jpg"];
    [alert setValue:imgv  forKey:@"image"];
```

to this:

```
UIImage *img= [UIImage imageNamed:@"kaga.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [alert setValue:img  forKey:@"image"];
```