# How to create view same as Touch ID or Alertview Pop Up Transparency?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I need to create a pop up view looks same as Alertview blur and white transparency (with dark black blackground) , Can any one give me some solution, I tried External libraries RTAlertview, LMAlertview but both looks little difference from Default one.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use UIAlertController?

Comment: Yes, But we need to add some icons inside pop view.

Comment: It's not possible to add an image to a UIAlertController. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37850312/4228969

Comment: Yes , Thats why i choose to be create custom view with same transparency/blur as default one.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I'm surprised LMAlertView didn't look like a native UIAlertView. Best of luck!