# Custom UIAlertController with image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertController implementation with two actions:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add your photo", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Later", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in }
let uploadAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Upload", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in }
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
alert.addAction(uploadAction)
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Now, I want to add an image (at center) below the title, with the two actions still being aligned as in the picture. What I have tried to do is create a UIImageView and add it to alertcontroller as:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myimage.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: alert.view.frame.width/2, y: alert.view.frame.height/2, width: 50, height: 50)
alert.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

But I cannot get it at the center of the alert. Is this the correct way? Or is there some other easy method to achieve this? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add image to UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059305/add-image-to-uialertcontroller)

Comment: UiAlertController doesn't support customization. Create or find a custom alert that does.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following extension which allows to fully customise UIAlertController:-

```
extension UIAlertAction{
    @NSManaged var image: UIImage?

    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIAlertActionStyle,image : UIImage?, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)? = nil ){
        self.init(title: title, style: style, handler: handler)
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `NSManaged` outside of Core Data? This is not the way to add stored variables in extensions. And certainly it's not a good idea.